Select last value before date in query
I am trying to run a query between 2 tables where I need the
Start Date
Final Date BEFORE the Milestone 1
Final Date BEFORE the Milestone 2
Finish Date



ID
Value
DATE




A
12
1/1/2024


A
15
1/2/2024


A
20
1/3/2024


A
22
1/4/2024


A
17
1/5/2024


A
19
1/6/2024


B
7
2/1/2024


B
9
2/2/2024


B
5
2/3/2024


B
8
2/4/2024


B
2
2/5/2024






ID
MileStone
DATE




A
Start
1/1/2024


A
1
1/3/2024


A
2
1/5/2024


A
Finish
1/6/2024


B
Start
2/1/2024


B
1
2/4/2024


B
Finish
2/5/2024



What I want the data to look like



ID
Value
Milestone




A
12
Start


A
15
1


A
22
2


A
19
Finish


B
7
Start


B
5
1


B
2
Finish



I tried a min value won't always work between 2 dates because I don't want the minimum value, I want the value with the minimum date

You forgot to post (as opposed to describe) how you tried to solve this problem.

"I tried ..." So where is this try???  We don't see it in this post.

So I started by getting the earliest time, which I could get using the following code:
Select
EARLIESTTIME.id,
dbo.flowsheet.[VALUE]
FROM
(Select
id,
MIN(dbo.flowsheet.FlowsheetDateTime) as [Start Date]
from dbo.Flowsheet
GROUP BY id) as EARLIESTTIME
JOIN dbo.flowsheet
ON (dbo.flowsheetB.id = EARLIESTTIME.patientid) AND (dbo.flowsheet.FlowsheetDateTime = EARLIESTTIME.[Start Date])
I then swapped our MIN with MAX to get the final time.
I assume I need to do for the next part is to create a subquery returning values from Start/Milestone 1, then running another for the Max value

Calculate date before Milestone
(select max(t1.date) maxdt from table1 t1 where t1.id=t2.id 
                    and t1.date<t2.date)

There t2.date - Milestone date. Maximum date before Milestone - maximum t1.date where t1.date<Milestone date.
Then take value at this date
(select max(value) from table1 t1_2 where t1_2.id=t2.id 
      and t1_2.date=(select max(t1.date) maxdt from table1 t1 where t1.id=t2.id 
                    and t1.date<t2.date)

Select value or max(value), if may be more then one row with this date.
See example
select ID,MileStone 
  ,case when Milestone in ('Start','Finish') then -- take value for current date
    (select max(value) from table1 t1_1 where t1_1.id=t2.id 
      and t1_1.date=t2.date
    )
   else
    (select max(value) from table1 t1_2 where t1_2.id=t2.id 
      and t1_2.date=(select max(t1.date) maxdt from table1 t1 where t1.id=t2.id 
                    and t1.date<t2.date)
    )
  end Value
  -- ,date
from table2 t2

